# WCF Rest Service to accept Json Data

Tags: asp.net

I want to convert Text Box data into JSON format and then post that JSON data to wcf rest service using post method ?

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you r correct....but i don't know how proceed

Comment: for this purpose use jquery ajax call to wcf with json data

Comment: look at my edited answer

Comment: in wcf service it gives error at this line " string FirstName = JsonData.Firstname;  "   on JsonData.Firstname.  kindly sort out this one

Answer (score 0):

Simple put this code on your aspx page and use correct service url

```
  var WCF_Service_URL = "http://your_service_ip/Service_name.svc/YourMethod";
    var myData = $('txtMyTextBox').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: WCF_Service_URL, 
        data: JSON.stringify(myData), // here convert into json format
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    });



   // wcf methods
            // 1) your IServices.cs interface method 
            [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "YourMethod")]
            string YourMethod(string JsonData);

            // 2) your Services.cs  

              public string YourMethod(string JsonData)
        {

           string FirstName = JsonData.Firstname; // your json object data 

                  // save here into database 

            return "Save successfully";

        }
```

Comment: Actually i have to convert form data into json format then after i have to send these converted json data to wcf service ....kindly reply with step by step procedure

Comment: ok the above line JSON.stringify(myData) converted  your data into json format and also this json type data to wcf

Comment: share your wcf code if do , and why you are using wcf for that

Comment: Actually i have to convert text boxes data into json format then after i have to send these converted json data to wcf service...ok........then after at wcf side i have convert these json data into normal form and have to save it in sql server database table.......this the requirment....kindly guide me...

Comment: and also how receive these data at wcf side

Comment: see the updated answer and follow this code , for query feel free to comment

Comment: I want to display name in textbox from database in asp.net mvc. i access the database through WCF service..kindly guid me

Comment: No that task completed ...now i just want to display name from database into TextBox Field ...after that I have edit that name and then save. BUT i am unable to display the name into textbox....if know kindly guid me.

Comment: get the name from database by services place this name viewbage and assign to textbox in view after editing

Comment: I am getting this error  "   The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'RMP_DataContract.Class_usp_getRegisteredPartnerList[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'RMP_DataContract.Class_usp_getRegisteredPartnerList'.  "

Comment: i have view which display data at load event ..and i also have one textbox for userID .the task is to search the record on the basis of userId and display on the same view......help me

Comment: UserId not to display in textbox but save it in hidden field

Comment: now help in following case...."   can we show file in a project which is uploaded into folder through another project within the same solution explorer in asp.net mvc   "

Comment: In a solution I have two project A & B ... I write a code to upload a file in project A....Now I want to view that file in Project B.....how to do this one

Comment: you say that your file is save in a separate folder in whatever place , but you can easily upload or show in any project .

Comment: i have show drop down value when i submit the form and success message shown on same page but drop down are not populated..

Comment: mark as answer this question first then put the new question for new answer.